# WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn bind to data from XmlDataProvider

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I've got an xml data like this bellow and I would like to bind a datagridcomboboxcolum to list all vendors - Surname for a given project(Datagrid context is already binded to combobox that selects a project).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ProjectList>
  <SingleProject id="1" name="TRP">
    <LanguageList>
      <Language id ="1">
        <TargetCode>en-gb</TargetCode>
        <TargetLanguageName>English</TargetLanguageName>
        <VendorList>
          <Vendor id="1">
            <Name>Karin</Name>
            <Surname>AAA</Surname>
            <GridPath>e:\stuff</GridPath>
          </Vendor>
          <Vendor id="2">
            <Name>Kate</Name>
            <Surname>BBB</Surname>
            <GridPath>e:\stuffss</GridPath>
          </Vendor>
        </VendorList>
      </Language>
    </LanguageList>
  </SingleProject>
</ProjectList>
```

Here is an XAML code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="XmlData" Source="../!setup.xml"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}">
        <Grid Margin="10,10,722,280">
            <TextBlock Text="Select:" Style="{StaticResource Heading2}" Margin="0,0,34,105" />
            <ComboBox x:Name="cmbSelect" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource XmlData}, XPath=/ProjectList/*}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,32,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123" Height="28">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
        </Grid>
        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="148,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="215" Width="707"
                  RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"
                  TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"                 
                  SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                  DataContext="{Binding ElementName=cmbSelect, Path=SelectedItem}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=./LanguageList/Language}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="All">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Language Code"
                                    Binding="{Binding XPath=TargetCode}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Language Name"
                                    Binding="{Binding XPath=TargetLanguageName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:name="dtcVendorName" Header="Vendor Name"
                                    Binding="{Binding XPath=VendorList/Vendor/Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:name="dtcVendorSurname" Header="Vendor Surname"
                                    Binding="{Binding XPath=VendorList/Vendor/Surname}"/>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:name="dcbVendorList" Header="Default Vendor"                                
                                        DisplayMemberPath="{Binding XPath=*}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I have a problem with binding DataGridComboBoxColumn "dcbVendorList" to list all vendors from an xml. Combobox should have a Surname displayed as an item.

Then based on the selection from a dcbVendorList, datagridtextcolumn "dtcVendorName" and "dtcVendorSurname" should be filled with data from this combobox.

I've tried to use Xpath * and . with no luck. It seems that a current item is "Language" xml node from a datacontext.

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:name="dcbVendorList" Header="Default Vendor" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding XPath=*}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to show the `Name` and `Surname` in one item, you have actually 2 content items. I think XPath cannot be used to get the  `Name` and `Surname` as one string result.

Comment: Ok, then in this case a Surname will be enough. Thanks for reading my question.